# Exceptions in Dynamo Mapped Pojo Setters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to have set/get methods that are mapped to Dynamo attributes through the mapping annotations throw exceptions such as IllegalArgumentException if, say, the input is a string but not formatted correctly.  More specifically is this possible for the Hash Key attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. If the data stored in your tables that you have mapped to POJO class with DynamoDBMapper annotations is valid according to the new validation code where you throw the IllegalArgumentException, then IllegalArgumentException will not be thrown by Mapper when it tries to read items and populate the POJO with the set methods. Scan, Query, GetItem etc could all fail on the client side with Mapper if an invalid attribute value is encountered. If there are invalid attribute values in your table, when you read items with DynamoDBMapper, the validation check in your POJO will fail, and you will not be able to read the invalid items, because DynamoDBMapper will call set method for the annotated attributes. You will also call the set method when creating new items before you DynamoDBMapper.save them.